# How to Obtain Image Bytes as String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, serialization, url-encoding

All I have is `<input type="file" name="myFileUpload" />`.

After the user chooses a file (most likely an image), how do I obtain the actual contents of the file as a string? (If possible, please tell me anything about base 64 and url encoding/decoding.)

I was asked to obtain such a string and set it as a value of a JSON object, then such a JSON object would be posted to the server "as is", that is, `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

I'm not sure if the above is a common practice since I'm accustomed to just posting such data as `multipart/form-data` which I was told not to use.

The receiver of this gigantic JSON object is an ASP.net Web API Controller. I suppose there would be a problem with deserialization if such an object is potentially multi-megabytes large.

So again, how to obtain the image bytes as a string and what problems may I encounter if I try to post such a large JSON object especially when it's received the server-side.

Comment: Take a look at [fileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and here is a possible [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aeZJe/) that may help with it.

Comment: I tried going down a similar route long time ago but I had some problems, I have opted to use the much simpler [FormData][1], server side I could access to the stream with context.Request.InputStream, not what you are asking for though.   
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects